# Difference between master site and materialized view site in oracle

Tags: oracle, replication

I'm learning the replication concept in oracle database. I have a confusion of these two terms - master site and materialized view site. Please help on this...

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have two databases, `DB1` and `DB2`. I want to replicate data from `DB1` to `DB2`. I created materialized views on `DB2` and these materialized views gets data (periodically) from tables stored on `DB1`.

So which is master site here?
The database from which replicated sites(`DB2` which has materialized views) gets data. In other words the database which stores master tables , which is `DB1` in our case.

then materialized view site?
The database which stores the materialized views, which is `DB2`.

**Documentation:**
[About Master Sites, Master Tables, and Materialized View Sites](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_reppit.htm#TDPII050)

Answer (score 2):

As per `Oracle Documentation` [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm) Oracle uses `materialized views` (also known as `snapshots` in prior releases) to replicate data to non-master sites in a replication environment and to cache expensive queries in a data warehouse environment.

`A materialized view is a replica of a target master from a single point in time`. The `master` can be either a `master table` at a `master site` or a `master materialized view` at a `materialized view site`. Whereas in multimaster replication tables are continuously updated by other master sites, materialized views are updated from one or more masters through individual batch updates, known as a refreshes, from a single master site or master materialized view site.

**For Example the Materialized View Connected to a Single Master Site**
[image]

Here a `materialized view site` communicating with one of `three master sites` ( That is (`orc1.world,orc2.world,orc3.world`) using a database link at the `materialized view site`( That is `mv1.world`), while the master sites communicate with each other using database links.

When a materialized view is fast refreshed, Oracle must examine all of the changes to the `master table` or `master materialized view` since the last refresh to see if any apply to the materialized view. Therefore, if any changes where made to the master since the last refresh, then a `materialized view` refresh takes some time to apply the changes to the `materialized view`. If, however, no changes at all were made to the master since the last refresh of a `materialized view`, then the `materialized view` refresh should be very quick.

> Why Use Materialized Views?

```
 1. Ease Network Loads 
 2. Create a Mass Deployment Environment
 3. Enable Data Subsetting
 4. Enable Disconnected Computing
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm#i34980
Oracle uses materialized views (also known as snapshots in prior releases) to replicate data to nonmaster sites in a replication environment and to cache expensive queries in a data warehouse environment.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/img/repln072.gif

So the materialized view site is used to avoid workload in the master site